# Wide tile notifcation on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any ideas how to create a wide tile on WP7?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft *used* to have this in their design and interaction guide:

> Double-width tiles are only available to Microsoft, phone manufacturers, and mobile operators.

I can't find anything equivalent in the current [User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) though.

Comment: @rudigrobler: dead link is dead

Answer (score 2):

It's still only available to Microsoft and their partner.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202884(v=VS.92).aspx
Can't reply to above answer

Answer (score 0):

We do not have the permissions to create a wide tile. Only Microsoft , mobile operators and mobile manufactures can only do that. See this- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202884(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this as this question is one of the top results in a search and the accepted answer is no longer valid.

Microsoft has a [page about wide tiles for Windows 7.8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that gives steps on how to do it.

Note that the steps are a little different, depending on whether you are using SDK 7.1 or SDK 8.0.

Basically, you add some code, check the OS version number, and run some other code if the OS is new enough.